# swift 3 get user information to whom data was shared

Tags: ios, swift, uiactivityviewcontroller

I am using `UIActivityViewController` to share data on different medias. How can I get user information to whom data was shared. Like if sharing is done on whatsapp than name of person or if sharing is done through mail than emailID of person.

Also how to get activity name on which data was shared like hangout, whatsapp etc

Comment: I don't think you will be able to get this data. Because your app creates the object to be shared on whatsaap. After that he sends it to whatsapp and whatsaap handles the rest.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get this information from UIActivityViewController. What you can do is invoke the action manually. For instance:

```
import MessageUI

let messageComposeViewController = MFMessageComposeViewController()
messageComposeViewController.messageComposeDelegate = self
messageComposeViewController.recipients = ["johnny@appleseed.com"]
messageComposeViewController.body = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"
navigationController?.presentViewController(messageComposeViewController, animated: true) {
    // ...
}
```

or

```
import MessageUI

let mailComposeViewController = MFMailComposeViewController()
mailComposeViewController.mailComposeDelegate = self
mailComposeViewController.setToRecipients(["johnny@appleseed.com"])
mailComposeViewController.setSubject("Hello")
mailComposeViewController.setMessageBody("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet", isHTML: false)
navigationController?.presentViewController(mailComposeViewController, animated: true) {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can not do that** with UIActivityViewController that is default control.
you can only get it's status of successfully share or not by the completion block of UIActivityViewController like this.

**Swift 3**

```
let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: objectsToShare, applicationActivities: nil)
activityVC.completionWithItemsHandler = {(activity: UIActivityType?, completed: Bool, returnedItems: [Any]?, error: Error?) in

        if (completed == true) {
            print("Share successfully")
        }
    }
    self.present(activityVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your app **cannot** communicate with an app that is not under your control in the first place in iOS. `UIActivityViewController` is just a means/medium to share objects to other apps. As soon as your pass on the data, the recipient app will take care of what it needs to do with it.